# change button switch toggle in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a button that when I click it changes the status of the record, but when I update, the color of the button does not change, if I refresh the page if it changes, how can I make the button change when I update the record

**Table:**

```
<div class="card-body">
<table id="tblProfiles" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>   
            <th>Status</th>                                  
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index">
            <td>{{ profile.description }}</td>
            <td>
                    <button
                    class="btn-sm"
                    :class="[profile.status == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger']"
                    @click="statusUpdate(profile.id)"
                    >{{profile.status == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}}
                    </button> 
            </td>                                   
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Details</button>                                                                           
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Method:**

```js
// ...
statusUpdate: async function(id) {                    
    try {
        const response = await profileService.activateDesactivate(id);
        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send profile object insted of id prop:

```js
<div class="card-body">
<table id="tblProfiles" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>   
            <th>Status</th>                                  
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index">
            <td>{{ profile.description }}</td>
            <td>
                    <button
                    class="btn-sm"
                    :class="[profile.status == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger']"
                    @click="statusUpdate(profile)"
                    >{{profile.status == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}}
                    </button> 
            </td>                                   
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Details</button>                                                                           
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Method receives profile objetc and update it as you want. In your case status prop changes the color class of your button.

```js
statusUpdate: async function(profile) {
                
                try {
                    
                    const response = await profileService.activateDesactivate(profile.id);
                    profile.status = 1;
                    console.log(response);                       

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }   
  },
```

Comment: Thanks that was the solution

Comment: add this to the method to validate the state and change the button :  if(response.data.data.status == 1) { profile.status = 1; } else { profile.status = 0; }

Comment: @Desarrollador You can improve code depending on api response.